# How to regenerate grid data on various button click event of a page while we are using telerik grid with LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik, linqdatasource

I am using Telerik grid control and LinqDataSource control on a page.

code :

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsFillGridData" runat="server" OnSelecting="ldsFillGridData_Selecting" />
```

all things working fine now i want to call its

```
protected void ldsFillGridData_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = from tc in db.city select tc;
}
```

this selecting event calling from some button click event. How???

I am trying like

```
ldsFillGridData_Selecting(null, null);
```

but it throws an error.

How to regenerate grid data on various button click event of a page while we are using telerik grid with LinqDataSource?

Comment: I am not sure if this is needed but you may need to handle the need_outsource event. In there you simply fill your dataset again. No need to rebind.  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/needdatasource/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Rebind() function of this telerik grid control, it will automatically calls ldsFillGridData_Selecting event and it shows updated records in Grid.

```
RadGrid.rebind();
```

Answer (score 0):

RadGrid1.Rebind();

Will rebind the grid, calling the select method of your datasource (as long as the linqdatasource is indicated as datasource for the grid).